# How do I delete my group post using facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is the function that I have used:

```
function deletePost(post_id){
    $.confirm({
        text: "Are you sure want to delete this post?",
        confirm: function(button) {
            var params3 = {};
            params3['access_token'] = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';                
            params3['method'] = 'DELETE';

            FB.api('/' + post_id + '', 'DELETE', params3,
             function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if(response.error.message){
                    alert(response.error.message);
                }
                else{
                    alert("Successfully Deleted!");
                }
             });
        },
        cancel: function(button) {
        }
    });
}
```

I have already used the following scope in permission settings:
{scope:'email, publish_stream, publish_actions, read_stream, manage_pages'}

I'm getting  the following response:

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Comment: Did you create the object (post) using the Application itself?

Comment: Yes! I created the post from my Application?